# Why are there no shadows on the ground?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, shadows

I am new to Blender and am having some trouble with shadows. I am making an image and I have positioned my camera and models, but when I render, there are no shadows on the ground

[image: I want shadows on the ground]

[image]

Please help me as shadows will give my project a more professional look.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post images of your current setup and lighting. What render engine are you using?

Comment: Here is my setup

Comment: Whoops Here is the setup :https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8lMs9Yq18T7MXE1MlpuUkU0WVk

Comment: I do not know what render engine is and what i am using. If you could please inform me about that

Comment: You appear to be using Blender internal renderer. There are no shadows on the ground because there is no ground to cast shadows on. If you want shadows create a ground object first.

Comment: How do i add a ground?

Comment: Do i just use a pane?

Comment: Yes, just Shift + A to add a plane.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you have no shadows on the ground is:

**Because there is no ground!**

You don't have any objects that will receive the shadow. Add a plane under your character.

Comment: Note also that by default in BI only Spot lamp can make objects cast shadows, and it appears that it isn't present in scene; to make others lamp cause casting shadows *Ray Tracing* in *Shading* rollout have to be enabled.